# Does parameters have to match case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and its Management Studio.

I am adding schemas in an existing database and there is a question I have regarding parameters. I noticed on a stored procedure page that the person has a parameter: `@PersonID int,`.

When I scroll down the page, so many times when he calls the parameter, he refers to it as `@personid`.

Does this actually make a difference in terms of functionality or performance or is it fine to keep it s it is?

The same applies to when calling a table. He has a table saved as 'Support.ErrorLog', but he calls it as below in his procedure:

```
insert into [support].[errorlog]...
```

Comment: Case in data comparison only matter if you use a case sensitive collation and it doesn't make a difference for parameters. SQL syntax in sql server is case insensivite `@Person` will equal `@person`. The same for table names etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** Case sensitiveness matters unless collation level is set as to ignore case sensitiveness. It does not matter in terms of functionality or performance.

If the code in question is working and in use, it seems that the database collation level is set to case insensitive.

You can verify this by running the following query

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));
```

Like on my server instance for a particular DB the result was

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Here `_CI_` means Case insensitive.

Had it been case sensitive the value would be something like

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

You can read more about collation at this excellent [MS knowledge base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)

Comment: It's pedantic and unrelated to the question, but I am pedantic, so can't not point out that [you should always specify a length when declaring, or converting to varchar](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). The default length used is 32 in the context you have used it, you would therefore truncate a number of collations - e.g. `SELECT name, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Name) FROM ::fn_helpcollations() WHERE name <> CONVERT(VARCHAR, Name);`